# criar PDF dinamicamente no RMarkdown

Tags: html, r, loop, pdf, rmarkdown

Boa tarde. Há uma semana estou tentando fazer uma mágica no RMarkdown mas não consigo. Bom, vamos lá.

Contextualizando: Eu preciso escrever diferentes PDFs (ou html) com diferentes conteúdos. No caso, este conteúdo diferente são apenas variáveis (temp minima, temp máxima... em casa pdf esses valors são diferente). 
Eu já fiz um código que pega os arquivos do sql, monta a base pra cada dia, e monta diferentes .txt com diferentes mensagens.

O que eu preciso agora é SALVAR diferentes PDFs (ou html) de forma automática usando o RMarkdown.

A justificativa disso é que estes PDFs/html são relatórios que serão enviados semanalmente a diferentes destinatários.

resumindo: Preciso criar PDFs/Html diferentes com conteúdo diferentes de forma automática.

Comment: Olá! Consegue nos fornecer algum código que já tentou e exemplificar melhor o que deseja fazer?

Answer (score 3):

Vou mostar aqui duas opções por meio de um exemplo. O exemplo será um data frame com duas colunas. Para cada linha da coluna, vou criar um `Rmd` que vai fazer a soma das duas colunas.

### Opção 1: um script `R` e um script `Rmd`

Você terá um script `R` principal que fará as análises e vai chamar o escript `Rmd` em um loop. O script `Rmd` terá então as diferentes variáveis que serão definidas no script `R`.

Script `R`:

```
# definir dados
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10))

for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
  rmarkdown::render('doc.Rmd', output_file = paste0('doc_linha_', i, '.pdf'))
}
```

Script `Rmd`:

````
---
  output: pdf_document
---

A média da linha `r i` do data frame `df` é:

```{r,echo=FALSE}
  mean(as.numeric(df[i, ]))
```
````

Como renderizamos o documento `Rmd` no mesmo *environment* que definimos o data frame `df`, não terá nenhum problema. Uma outra opção é o argumento [`params`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-declare.html) da função `rmarkdown::render()`

### Opção 2: somente um script `R`

Essa opção é interessante quando precisamos que o texto seja tão flexível quanto o código. No seguinte exemplo vamos adicionar o nome da linha presente no data frame como parte do texto no documento markdown:

````
# definir dados
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), names = paste('Linha', LETTERS[1:10]))

# Para cada loop
  # 1. criamos um documento markdown
  # 2. renderizamos o documento em pdf

for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
  # criar documento rmarkdown
File = paste0('---
  title: Título para ', df[i, 'names'], '
  output: pdf_document
---

A média da ', print(df[i, 'names']), ' do data frame `df` é:

```{r,echo=FALSE}
  mean(as.numeric(df[i, ]))
```
')

  # salvar documento
  writeLines(File, 'doc.Rmd')

  # renderizar documento
  rmarkdown::render('doc.Rmd', output_file = paste0('doc_linha_', i, '.pdf'))
}

# deletar documento temporário
file.remove('doc.Rmd')
````